# When do superclasses not have a default constructor?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor

According to the [Java tutorial on constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
> must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
> no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.
> **This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
> superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
> superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
> that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
> implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
> constructor.**

If you have a superclass `A` that has no explicit default constructor, 
and a subclass `B extends A` that has no explicit default constructor,

And in the main method of a driver class you do 
`A obj1 = new A();` 
a default constructor will be created, 
which will call the default constructor of the Object class, correct?

But if you do 
`B obj2 = new B();` 
according to the tutorial, a default constructor for B will be generated, 
 and the constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass, 
 which will in turn call the constructor in Object.

So when will the superclass not have a no-argument constructor?

Answer (score 8):

The default constructor is defined by the compiler when you don't provide one.

So this

```
public class A{}
```

Would be represented by the compiler somewhat as:

```
public class A
  public A() {
    super(); //invokes Object's default constructor
  }
}
```

Since my definition of `A` did not have an explicit constructor defined.

In the example above `A` extends `Object` implicitly and `Object's` default constructor is automatically invoked by the compiler when it does `super()`. The same is true for any classes that may extend `A`, for example:

```
public class B extends A {}
```

would be implemented by the compiler somewhat like:

```
public class B extends A {
   public B() {
      super(); //invokes A's default constructor
   }
}
```

Which as you can see will end up chaining `Object`'s default constructor, then `A`'s default constructor and finally `B`'s default constructor.

**> So when will the superclass not have a no-argument constructor?**

It won't have a no-arg constructor when you define one explicitly. For example, if I changed my definition of `A` to

```
public class A {
   public A(String name){}
}
```

Then `A` no longer has a default constructor and I can no longer do this

```
public class B extends A {
   //Uh oh, compiler error. 
   //Which parent class constructor should the compiler call?
}
```

Now `B` must explicitly chain the right constructor from its parent class by explicitly stating which one to use. For example

```
public class B extends A {
   B() {
     super("B"); //Now the compiler knows which constructor to invoke
   }
}
```

**Java Decompiler Demonstration**

You can in fact demonstrate all of this by using a tool that comes with your JDK. There is a program in your JDK bin directory called `javap`. This is the Java Decompiler tool, which lets you take a look at code generated by the compiler.

You could compile my examples and then decompile them to look at the generated code, e.g.

```
javac A.java
javap A
```

And the decompiler will show you:

```
public class A {
  A();
}
```

Which clearly shows the compiler added a default constructor.

You may disassemble the class to see the byte codes.

```
javac B.java
javap -c B
```

And it will show how it invokes the parent class default constructor

```
class B extends A {
  B();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1 // Method A."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

If I add a default parameter to the `A`'s constructor, you will see the compiler no longer provides the default constructor, it just provides the one I defined explicitly:

```
class A {
    A(String name){}
}
```

Then I can do

```
javac A.java
javap A
```

And it yields

```
class A {
  A(java.lang.String);
}
```

Which demonstrates that what you read in the specification you cited in the original question is true.

Answer (score 2):

> So when will the superclass not have a no-argument constructor?

If you add any other constructor of superclass but forget to add no-arg constructor the compiler will complain. In this case the default constructor of superclass is not provided.

Answer (score 1):

> And in the `main` method of a driver class you do
>
> ```
> A obj1 = new A();
> ```
>
> a default constructor will be created

There is nothing you can do in the `main` method of a driver to create a default constructor. If it is defined, you can use it; if it is not defined, you get a compile error.

> So when will the superclass not have a no-argument constructor?

When it has other constructors, all of which taking *some* arguments. Here is an example:

```
class SuperA {
    public SuperA(String str) { ... }
    public SuperA(int num) { ... }
}
```

Above, `SuperA` has two constructors - one taking a `String`, and another one taking an `int`. Neither of them is default, because they take parameters.

If you make a derived class `DerivedB extends SuperA` and do not define any constructors, you would get a compile error.