# Inheritance of constructors in java

Tags: java, class-constructors, inheriting-constructors

Whenever any constructor is called in any derived class the task gets accomplished only by eventually calling the base class constructor implicitly or explicitly
(correct me if I am wrong here).

Since we intended to create an instance of the derived class, but since the base class constructor is called in the end.

So, how is an instance of the derived class is constructed despite the constructor of base class being called upon?

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you're asking. If you want to use the constructor of the base class, you can call it with `super` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644317/126416)

Comment: You may find this other question relevant to your investigation: [When does super classes not have a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392884/697630)

Comment: What do you mean by “despite the constructor of the base class being called upon”?

Comment: Ya i think i was wrong in there,

Comment: I got the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't think of the constructor as *creating* the instance. Think of it as *initializing* the instance, with respect to that particular class.

So the initialization process looks something like:

- Allocate memory
- Initialize object from perspective of `java.lang.Object`
- Initialize object from perspective of `your.package.Superclass`
- Initialize object from perspective of `your.package.Subclass`

(Even though you start with a call to `new Subclass(...)`, the superclass constructor body is executed first.)

The details of object initialization are given in [JLS section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac: Glad to hear it's working for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Constructor is not very fortunate name. It may suggest that it is responsible for *creating* (constructing) object, but in reality it is responsible for *initialization* of *already existing* object.

Object is created by `new` operator. But that object is "set up" to have all its fields filled with default values: null, false, 0 (depending on type). To make such object *usable* in our application we need to "set it up" (initialize) properly and that is the job of constructor.

But since classes can extend other classes it is required from constructors of subclass to execute its code only after execution of constructor of superclass (for instance to make sure that all inherited fields are properly initialized so we could use in our constructor inherited methods which actually use those superclass fields). Which is why `super(..)` call is placed explicitly or implicitly at start of every constructor (except `Object` class since it doesn't extend other class).